# Graph theory proof about triangles.

Tags: graph-theory

Getting a bit stuck on this question:

Prove that if any graph $H$ has $\delta (H)> \frac{n}{2}$ then $H$ contains a triangle. ($\delta (H)$ means the smallest degree of a vertex in H)

So far I have proved that $\delta (H)> \frac{n}{2} \implies H$ contains a cycle but I'm not sure how to use that to show $H$ contains a triangle.

Any help?

Comment: Please don't erase the question, in case someone else wants to ask something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Consider any edge in $H$, and call its endpoints $u$ and $v$.  What can you say about how many neighbours $u$ has?  What about $v$?  Is there anything that might force $u$ and $v$ to have a neighbour in common?  What can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can also use special case of Turan theorem: Let $H = (V,E)$. If $\#E \geq \frac{n^2}{4}$ then H contains a triangle. So if $\delta(H) > \frac{n}{2}$, then $2\#E = \sum_{v \in V}d(v) \geq n\frac{n}{2} = \frac{n^2}{2}$.